# Why Next.js revalidate complete with gatewayTimeout?

Tags: next.js, vercel

My revalidate function worked well for a while, not now, why `gatewayTimeout` happen?

```js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    // Check for secret to confirm this is a valid request
    if (req.query.secret !== process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_TOKEN) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid token' })
    }

    try {
        if (req.query.programId) {
            await res.revalidate(
                `/${req.query.organizationShortId}/program/${req.query.programId}`
            )
            return res.json({ revalidated: true })
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).send('Error revalidating')
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do the server logs show?

Comment: `Task timed out after 10.01 seconds`

Comment: The corresponding getStaticPaths or getStaticProps is not get called. So not that one holds it.